# Kinetic often shows a '?' over the network icon

Tags: networking, indicator, statusbar

[image]

I have two computers on Ubuntu 22.10 and they often show a question mark over the WIFI icon or NETWORK icon.

Even though the network works just fine, and it has perfectly good connections.

The icon goes back to normal as soon as I just open up the settings app.

Why is gnome confused about the status of my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in Ubuntu 22.10 which is [described here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1844897).

Answer (score 3):

> Even though the network works just fine, and it has perfectly good
> connections.

The question mark ? generally means that you are connected to the wireless access point, usually a router, but at the last connectivity check, access to the internet, beyond the router, was not found.

I believe it is caused by power saving, either in Network Manager, your wireless device or perhaps even the router itself.

Power saving schemes are designed to partially power down when not in use and to, ideally, spring back to life seamlessly when needed again.

If the network, as you said, works just fine, I wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: I've noticed this happening occasionally in 22.10. After a while it tends to show the correct connectivity. Network is fine from the start despite the "?".